# How To Passing A TextBox To A Class Property

Tags: c#-4.0

I have the next class `Class1` with one property:

```
TextBox nsender;

public TextBox Nsender
{
  get { return nsender; }
  set { nsender = value; }
}
```

I use this code:

```
Class1 c=new Class1{Nsender=TextBox1};
```

But `Nsender` Is Still `Null`.

Comment: Where are you accessing Nsender?

Comment: is your TextBox1 not null? and also make sure Nsender is not being set to null elsewhere in the code.

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan : In ButtonClick, in a form

Comment: @Amn: TextBox1 Is not Null,No

Comment: i just tried using your exact code in a simple winforms app, and the Nsender gets populated fine. Its not null. Where exactly have u put this code ? Class1 c=new Class1{Nsender=TextBox1}; If your object c is out of scope then NSender can be null. Make sure the object "c" is declared at some global or form level.